# Antidote 9 with TeXmaker and special characters

Tags: texmaker

I'm trying to use the Antidote 9 software, a spell checker with TeXmaker. When I copy the text in TeXmaker and paste it in Antidote, all special characters (é, à, è, etc.) are encoded to *Ã§*, *Ã©*, *Ã¨*, etc.

Anybody know why ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know Antidote; it seems like Antidote's output is UTF-8 encoded, but you're using `latin1` or `latin9`.

Comment: Having the same problem from Safari to Antidote. Anyone have a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround suggested in [Antidote 9 guide for windows](https://www.antidote.info/en/antidote-9/documentation/user-guide/using-with-your-other-software/windows/latex) is to open the `.tex` file with another intermediate editor and copy-paste it into Antidote’s internal editor. I had the same problem and could solve it with the [default windows notepad](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-notepad/9msmlrh6lzf3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Step by step instructions can be found one [the linux guide of the same version of Antidote](https://www.antidote.info/en/antidote-9/documentation/user-guide/using-with-your-other-software/linux/latex)

Depending on how your latex file is encoded, you may have to first encode it in `utf-8` (in `TexMaker`, go to the `Edit` menu and select `Setup Encoding...`)

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Mac, you have to use MacRoman characters. Antidote doesn't support fancy characters unless they are MacRoman.

Comment: Specifically, MacOS provides the console command `iconv -i UTF-8 -o MACINTOSH < input-in-UTF-8.txt > output-in-Mac-Roman.txt`.